# How do I print an 2D array by means of a pointer? c++

Tags: c++

I created a 2D array, and made a pointer to point to the first element. I'm trying to print  the 2D array, using the pointer but I'm getting the following error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

> source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: source_file.cpp:15:27:
>   error: invalid types ‘char[int]’ for array subscript
>            cout << pname[x][y] << endl;

```
                       ^

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name[2][2] = {'E', 'f', 'g', 'r'};
  char* pname = &name[0][0];

  for (int x = 0; x<2; x++)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y<2; y++)
      {
        cout << pname[x][y] << endl;  
      }  
  }
}
```

Comment: Your array looks like one dimentional

Comment: pname is not a 2d Array it is a char*

Comment: Why do you want to take a pointer to `name`? That might help with a more substantial answer.

Comment: @ForeverStudent  pname is supposed to be a pointer to my 2 D array.

Comment: Why not just use `name[x][y]`?  What is the pointer usage supposed to do for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like:

```
  #define x_size 2
  [...]
  char (*pname)[x_size] = &name[0];

  for (int x = 0; x<2; x++)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y<2; y++)
      {
        cout << pname[x][y] << endl;  
      }  
  }
```

or:

```
  int x_size = 2;
  char* pname = &name[0][0];

  for (int x = 0; x<2; x++)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y<2; y++)
      {
        cout << pname[x*x_size + y] << endl;  
      }  
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

`pname` is a pointer to `char`. So `pname[x]` is a `char`. Therefore `pname[x][y]` is an attempt to take the yth item from a char, just as if you'd typed `char t; t[10];`.

Assuming you want to pass a pointer because you want to pass by reference, you want to take an argument of `char pname[][10]`.

If you just want to output the items linearly, use your current `pname` and step along `for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++) cout << pname[c] << endl;`.

Comment: @Tomyy oh I see.. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is, the `char*` type drops the array size information from the C-style 2-D array `name`.  Because `pname` is just a `char*`, its users have no way of knowing the size and shape of the thing it's pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
int main() {
    char name[2][2] = {{'E', 'f'}, {'g', 'r'}};
    char pname[2][2];
    memcpy(pname, name, sizeof (char)*2*2);

    for (int x = 0; x<2; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y<2; y++) {
            cout << pname[x][y] << endl;  
        }  
    }
}
```

It would output: 
`E`
`f`
`g`
`r` with newlines inbetween

look up memcopy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225850/c-c-how-to-copy-a-multidimensional-char-array-without-nested-loops)

Comment: Answers the question by changing the parameters of the question and then answering the new question. Very Kobayashi Maru.