# Copy from 2d dynamic char array to another 2d dynamic array in c

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays, memcpy

I wanted to copy the content of a two dimensional array into another two dimensional char array. I used the following `for` loop with `memcpy` but it is not working as desired. So I have two questions.

1. What is wrong with this code? and
2. Is there a way to do it without use of iteration?

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       memcpy(&buf_copy[i], buf[i], sizeof(buf[i]));
   }
   ```

Both `buf` and `buf_copy` are 2d dynamic char arrays.

Edit: declarations of the arrays

```
char **buf;
char **buf_copy;
```

EDIT 2: Here is how memory is allocated to them

```
void intit_buf()
{
    buf = (char**)malloc(BUFFER * sizeof(*buf));
    for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER; i++)
        buf[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 33);

    //initialize buf_copy
    buf_copy = (char**)malloc(BUFFER * sizeof(*buf_copy));
    for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER; i++)
        buf_copy[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 33);
}
```

Comment: *"Both buf and buf_copy are 2d dynamic char arrays"* - I have a strong suspicion they are not. That there is pointer business going on, and you fail because you don't understand what `sizeof` would do in that case.

Comment: When you say "2d dynamic char arrays" do you mean `char **`? Then you have multiple problems. Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Post a mimal complete exaple please!

Comment: I see. Then I'm tempted to offer this is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: How did you allocate memory for your arrays?

Comment: @Marievi I allocated memory using malloc()

Comment: @John_D show as that code too. Post a minimal example *complete* example please.

Comment: `sizeof(buf[i])` will be the size of a pointer, not the length of the string or the size of the memory in `buf[i]`.

Comment: Use `memcpy(buf_copy[i], buf[i], 33);`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie comment answer and the answer below answers my first question. How about my second question? Is it possible to do it without iteration?

Comment: @John_D I updated the answer to answer your second question too.

Comment: No, it cannot be done without ireation because `malloc` may not have returned contigeous memory.

Comment: WHAT IS WITH THE DOWNVOTE? Nobody can learn without making mistakes!!

Comment: See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays), it explains why memcpy doesn't work, why your current code is _not_ a 2D array, and what you can use instead.

Comment: John, although I did not downvote your question, your erroneous use of `sizeof`, thinking it will return the size of dynamically allocated memory, is worthy of a downvote (you didn't read the book).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is wrong with this code?

The first and last parameters of the function call.

Change this:

```
memcpy(&buf_copy[i], buf[i], sizeof(buf[i]));
```

to this:

```
memcpy(buf_copy[i], buf[i], 33);
```

since you need to give the size of the column, not the size of a pointer!

Moreover, notice that you need to pass `buf_copy`, just like you did for `buf`, without taking the address of it or something, since [`memcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) expects pointers for its two first parameters, and `buf_copy[i]` and `buf[i]` are pointers already.

> Is there a way to do it without use of iteration?

It cannot be done without ireation because `malloc()` may *not* have returned contigeous memory. Read more in [C / C++ How to copy a multidimensional char array without nested loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225850/c-c-how-to-copy-a-multidimensional-char-array-without-nested-loops)

---

PS: Unrelated to your problem, but in general: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No!

Comment: What do you think about my second question though?

Comment: Now i can accept your answer. Earlier I didn't want my question marked "answered" soon because I was waiting for reply regarding my second question. And the dimension of the array is known at compile time. Thanks for the link

Comment: More general, as soon as we talk about an array of pointers to rows which are dynamicallt allocated, it cannot be done without iteration. `char a[10][20]` is a contigeous block of memory, so is `char b[n][m]`. But `char **c` with `c=malloc(n*sizeof(char *))` will not result in a 2-dimensional array of contigeous memory.

Comment: Right, @PaulOgilvie thanks for helping me improve the answer!